# Django keeps saying field is required even if the fields are already provided

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My View:

```
code = 111
score = 3
test = models.Test.objects.filter(code__iexact=code)[0]
first_name = data['first_name']
last_name = data['last_name']
password = data['password']

form = forms.EntryForm(data=data)

if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.test = test
    form.instance.first_name = first_name
    form.instance.last_name = last_name
    form.instance.password = password
    form.instance.score = score

    form.save(commit=True)
```

Running this however will give me this warning saying `test` and `score` fields are required:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>test<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>score<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

But as you can see, all the fields are already provided. It doesn't also give an error for `first_name`, `last_name` and `password` so I guess Django have read that one. Here is my Entry model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Test: {t} | By: {f} {l}".format(t=self.test, f=self.first_name, l=self.last_name)
```

And the form:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = '__all__'
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: first of all can you print the content of `data` dictionary and second of all what is the purpose of the whole `form_valid` part - thats exactly what the form object would do when calling `save()`. Please describe what you want to achieve so we can help u out. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the *form* is invalid as *data* does not have `score` and `test`. So, appending this to data should work:

```
code = 111
score = 3
data['score'] = score
test = models.Test.objects.filter(code__iexact=code)[0]
data['test'] = test
first_name = data['first_name']
last_name = data['last_name']
password = data['password']

form = forms.EntryForm(data=data)

if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.test = test
    form.instance.first_name = first_name
    form.instance.last_name = last_name
    form.instance.password = password
    form.instance.score = score

    form.save(commit=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a value for `test`, `code` and `score`. since that is not in the POST data itself. A form only inspects the `data` you pass to it, but these do not appear in the data. You cann make a form that excludes this:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        exclude = ['test', 'code', 'score']
```

Then you can run the form with:

```
form = forms.EntryForm(data=data)
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.test = models.Test.objects.get(code__iexact=code)
    form.instance.code = 111
    form.instance.score = 3
    form.save()
```

The form thus does *not* look to local variables, it only looks to the data passed explicitly. It would be quite "unstable" to do so anyway, imagine that later you declare a variable `score` somehow, but you do not know that the form has a field `score` as well, then you would, unwillingly, change the logic of that method.